# Is there a way to "clipToBounds" Particles within a UIView in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, particles

I've done some searching and haven't run across someone trying to accomplish this yet. I have a particle emitter within a small UIView and I would like to keep the particles from leaving the UIView. So for example, when a particle approaches the border of the view, it would "slide-under" and disappear. Currently the particles fly out of the UIView border and into the surrounding views. If this isn't clear, I can try to clarify any questions you may have. Thank you.

-PS: Another possible solution would be to have the particles "bounce" off the UIView boundary, if this is a possibility.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Particle Border Image]

Comment: So you're using `CAEmitterLayer`? Have you tried `masksToBounds`?

Comment: Yes, I have, that has no effect. The particles still leave the bounds of the UIView.

Comment: And yes, I'm using a custom implementation of CAEmitterLayer.

Comment: Show the code for your custom stuff. Also, show how the emitter layer and the view are related, what are their frames.